# Get Object type of class for ArrayList

Tags: java, class, reflection

So, I've tried to get object type of a given class to parse into ArrayList
Example:

```
public class Util{
    public static void makeArray(String tag, Class<?> forClass) {
        ArrayList<?> list = new ArrayList();
    }
}
```

How can I replace `<?>` with `forClass` object type?
So back in main method when I call

```
Util.makeArray("names", String.class);
```

It would create `ArrayList<String>` and if I say

```
Util.makeArray("ages", int.class);
```

It would resolve it to `ArrayList<Integer>`

And if it is not even done this way, show how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would use a method type parameter.

```
public static <T> void makeArray(String tag, Class<T> forClass) {
    ArrayList<T> list = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

This can be called using `Util.<String>makeArray("names", String.class)` or you can let the compiler infer `T` by omitting the `<String>`.